# Need to remove html tags from <td></td> area in SharePoint custom DispForm.aspx

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery

I had created a custom DispForm.aspx for a SharePoint list, using SharePoint designer. I included a Rich Text column type to show in DispForm.aspx. The contents of the column are showing, but somehow the html tags are also showing.

For example, if the value contains -

**This is in Bold**

List -

- item 1
- item 2

Then the text in DispForm shows -

"<strong>Bold text</strong> <br>List - <ul><li> item 1</li><li> item 2</li></ul>"

The value in the column shows properly when viewing in the list view itself.

Upon examining the DispForm.aspx in SharePoint Designer, the value of the column is coded as <xsl:value-of select="@Progress_x0020_Comments" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>

where **@Progress_x0020_Comments** is the value of the column.

When I inspect the final HTML rendering of the page, the contents of the column is displayed inside <td></td> tag.

Any idea how I can remove the html tags?

Comment: Sorry for a mistake - the "disable-output-escaping" attribute was missing (i included it in my question by mistake). I included this attribute for the column i was speaking of, and it has solved the problem!

Comment: Make sure you set this as an answer so that people who might have the same problem see your question is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

My problem solved -

Upon examining the DispForm.aspx page in SharePoint Designer, as I have mentioned before, the content of the Multiple Lines Rich Text type column is displayed using the XSLT code -

<xsl:value-of select="@Progress_x0020_Comments"/>

The solution is to include the attribute "disable-output-escaping" and set it to "yes"

So the XSLT code should be -

<xsl:value-of select="@Progress_x0020_Comments" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>